# Office 365 Exchange ActiveSync using OAuth

Tags: azure, office365, activesync, microsoft-graph-api, intune

Ever since https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2016/06/13/announcing-exchange-activesync-version-16-1/ was posted there has been zero articles or blogs that cover how to configure Exchange ActiveSync in Office 365 to use OAuth.

Specifically:

- Is there something you need to configure for Exchange Online or modify any ADFS Claims
- What scope and endpoints should be utilized

Comment: Did you figure out the scopes etc?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

Resource: `https://outlook.office365.com/`

Scope: `full_access_as_user`

The description for this is "Access mailboxes as the signed-in user via Exchange Web Services". However I think the description is wrong because I disabled EWS, and it still worked, using this as a Bearer token in the Auth header via ActiveSync.